# Spinnaker and custom Cloudwatch metrics for scaling policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, spinnaker

I'm currently trying to get around the issue in AWS where CloudWatch alarms cannot contain more than one metric (in this case, SQS message counts).

Scenario:

I have an ASG that contains a set amount of on-demand instances for my application. I have another ASG, where I plan on using spot instances to scale out when it gets busy.

What I'm trying to achieve is, for my application that consumes from 3 SQS queues

- if at least 1 queue has a message count above the threshold, scale out the spot instances ASG
- if ALL queues have a message count below the threshold for at least X minutes, scale in

To get around this I'm attempting to publish a custom metric with a count of how many queues have a message count above a certain limit, and then use this metric to decide whether to scale in my auto scaling groups.

However... in Spinnaker, there doesn't seem to be a way to refer to a custom metric (from the UI at least) - I am missing something here or is it just not possible?

From what I understand as well, you can only publish metric data to your own namespaces - attempting to publish to any 'AWS/*' namespace will result in an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings.js file for deck, include the following block:

```
providers: {
  aws: {
    // ...
    metrics: {
      customNamespaces: ['yourcustomnamespace'],
    },
    // ...
  }
}
```

I don't think this is explicitly documented anywhere - you'd have to dig into the source code to find this bit of configuration.

Comment: Finally got round to trying this today and works with no issues - I had been going through the clouddriver code, never thought of checking here!